# How is .Ap0 interpreted in following C program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%f",0x6effff10.Ap0);
    return 0;
}
```

Above code gives the printed value as 1862270736.625000. What is the representation mean after the decimal?

Explanation of the use post decimal value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0x6effff10.Ap0` is a hexadecimal floating-point constant. The `A` goes with the digits and period to its left; the significand is `6EFFFF10.A`. The `p` introduces a power of two to scale the significand by, similar to the `e` for the decimal exponent of decimal floating-point constants. It means 6EFFFF10.A<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>0</sup>.